# Confused about blocking channels

Tags: go

I have this block of code that is supposed to wait 10 seconds before the program exits, but it only works if I add some sort of print something for it afterwards. Why is that? I want it to wait 10 seconds without having to uncomment that print statement.

```
func main() {

  forever := make(chan bool)
  go func() {
    fmt.Println("why")
    time.Sleep(10*time.Second)
    //fmt.Println("here")
    forever <- false
  }()
  fmt.Println("forever")
  <- forever

}
```

This also works:

```
func main() {

  forever := make(chan bool)
  go func() {
    fmt.Println("why")
    time.Sleep(10*time.Second)
    forever <- false
  }()
  fmt.Println(<- forever)

}
```

---

The following program does not wait for 10 seconds when it is run in Go playground:

```
package main

import (
    "time"
)

func main() {
    forever := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
        forever <- false
    }()
    <-forever
}
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your problem. As it stands, this code does what you want it to. I removed the print statements.

Comment: @squiguy strange, i'm using the go playground and it still does this

Comment: I see it waits when it runs in terminal and it does not wait on playground.

Comment: @squiguy here is the code that ends abruptly https://play.golang.org/p/j3jUWuJr6VB and here is the code that waits 10 seconds https://play.golang.org/p/L_WlXRGUcU9

Comment: I'm fairly certain the playground has a sandboxed environment so it will limit execution time. Try waiting for one second.

Comment: @squiguy https://play.golang.org/p/EesYvQWvMrW yeah it's still not waiting. But okay it seems it's a bug with playground just wanted to make sure I wasn't misunderstanding something completely... Thanks for your help

Comment: yes this is an issue with the go playground.. i created a main.go on my local machine and the code works as expected sans all the fmt calls.

Comment: Technically, it's a "feature" of the playground. When everything is blocked waiting on time in the playground, time will artificially advance until things unblock... or it decides things are deadlocked. See "Faking Time" section in the playground article https://blog.golang.org/playground

Comment: @RayfenWindspear Your comment should be promoted to answer.

Comment: @GrzegorzŻur That can be arranged...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, it's a "feature" of the playground. When everything is blocked waiting on time in the playground, time will artificially advance until things unblock... or it decides things really are deadlocked. See "Faking Time" section in the [Golang Playground article](https://blog.golang.org/playground#TOC_3.1.).